# how to get SUM() of COUNT() column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

i have the following query, tried using case statement

```
SELECT t.inst_id, t.inst_username, tcm.city_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN psb.pms_student_bucket_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_assiged,
SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(psb.pms_student_bucket_id) BETWEEN 1 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1-50',
SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(psb.pms_student_bucket_id) > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' > 50'
FROM tbl_si_di t
JOIN tbl_city_master tcm ON tcm.city_id = t.city_ref_id
JOIN tbl_si_students tss ON tss.inst_ref_id = t.inst_id
LEFT JOIN pms_student_bucket psb ON psb.user_ref_id = tss.user_ref_id
GROUP BY t.inst_id;
```

I need SUM of pms_student_bucket_id column when their COUNT is '1-50' and '>50'. Right now this query is saying `Invalid use of group function`.

How would I SUM on COUNT of "pms_student_bucket_id" equals/between some value in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put it in a subquery

```
SELECT inst_id, inst_username, city_name, 
    SUM(pms_student_bucket_id IS NULL ) AS not_assiged,
    SUM(num_bucket >=10 AND num_bucket <= 20) AS '10 - 20'
    SUM(num_bucket <= 50) AS '1-50',
    SUM(num_bucket > 50) AS ' > 50'
FROM
(   SELECT t.inst_id, t.inst_username, tcm.city_name,psb.pms_student_bucket_id,     
        COUNT(psb.pms_student_bucket_id) as num_bucket
    FROM tbl_si_di t
    JOIN tbl_city_master tcm ON tcm.city_id = t.city_ref_id
    JOIN tbl_si_students tss ON tss.inst_ref_id = t.inst_id
    LEFT JOIN pms_student_bucket psb ON psb.user_ref_id = tss.user_ref_id
    GROUP BY t.inst_id
)t1
GROUP BY inst_id;
```

note you can use the boolean values returned to do what you want.. aka you don't need a case statement, the boolean value returns a 1 or 0 which can then be summed..

Comment: thanks, how can i write the above to get the sum when the count is between 10-20 ?

Comment: @sam i just edited... you can put in multiple conditions for the boolean result :) i included >= 10 and <= 20 to include 10 and 20 you can remove the equals if you don't want to include them :)

Comment: why can't i use num_bucket value for the first 'not_assiged' column? like SUM(num_bucket < 1 ) AS 'not_assiged' ?

Comment: @sam I'm not sure what you mean... num_bucket is the count of pms_student_bucket_id... so if you want to see when its less than 1 just do `SUM(num_bucket = 0) as not_assigned`

Comment: oh no, its not actually sum the num_bucket rows count, it just returning 1 even when there are more rows in pms_student_bucket table